# Iframe with login form

Tags: html, forms, iframe

I have a target-URL (lets say https://www.example.org/xxx/yyy/) which I want to be available from an easier URL, on another domain (lets say https://easy.example.com/). To accomplish that, I use a full page iframe. I think this is the best option, because otherwise it can only be redirected, while I want the easy URL to stay intact.

This works fine, except for the fact that the target-URL has a login-form. Within the iframe, I can not submit the form: it will create a blank page. On the direct target-URL the form works fine of course.

How can I solve this, and display the whole website on my URL, including a working form? Or is this not possible?

Comment: `target.com` and `domain.com` are real websites. Please don't use them for examples. `example.com`, `example.net` and `example.org` are reserved for that purpose.

Comment: maybe with some code that would be easier to understand your problem... I already did some form post through iframes, and it worked fine... this should work for you too... need more information, details,...

Comment: " it will create a blank page. " — Look in your browser's developer tools. What does the console say? (Here's guessing X-Frame-Options is banning your frame)

Comment: Thanks for the hint Quentin. I think it has something to do with the secured HTTPS-connection, which is blocking some content.